# C# Manipulating XSL-FO document

Tags: xsl-fo

I have an XSL-FO document which later will be converted into a PDF using a XSL-FO to PDF engine (fonet).

In the XSL-FO document I am paying attention to two fields (blocks) of text, well in fact they are cells of a table. I need both fields to keep in the same page after converting document to PDF.

I am wondering if there is any way to know if both fields will be put into the same or different page once converted to PDF? In case of it is detected they will be put on different pages, could I manipulate the XSL-FO in some manner to get both fields placed in the same page once document is converted to PDF? or is there any way to indicate within XSL-FO document through some attribute that these two fiedls cannot be separated into different pages and always must keep in the same page?

I have googled and found [here](https://naanwikicode.blogspot.com.es/2011/08/xslt-how-to-keep-content-together-in.html) that there is an attribute that can be set for XSL FO tables in order to keep some table elements in the same page. Is there any easy way to manipulate the XSL-FO document to add this attribute? The items I want to mantain in the same page are adjacent, one after another, but they belong to different tables.

Comment: keep-together on the table row. but I would suspect that the XSL FO engine you are using does not support it.

Comment: @KevinBrown and do you know some free XSL-FO engine that supports it and also pdf forms? I have googled and all tools are not free. And from XSL-FO, how can I manipulate it from C# to add this attribute? is there any free tool for maninpulate XSL-FO documents?